# Is it possible to pass a React Component as argument in between functions of a Container Component

Tags: reactjs

Passing Child Components as arguments to functions of Parent Component and trying to render does not work

```js
//React Container Component
//Import Both Views and Render based on preference
import PosterView from "./PosterView"
import ListView from "./ListViewCard"

...

renderCardsBasedOnType(cardType){
  if(cardType === "poster"){
     return this.renderCards(PosterView)
  }else{
     return this.renderCards(ListViewCard)
  }
}
renderCards(component){
  let cards =  this.props.list.map(function(cardData){
     return <component data={cardData}/>
   })
  return cards
}
render(){
  let cards = this.renderCardsBasedOnType("poster")
  return <div>{cards}</div>
}
......
```

Comment: Can I have multiple returns? like `return this.renderCards(PosterView)` and `return this.renderCards(ListViewCard)` Without the `if`

Comment: or can I call them from an other component? how?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Try `Component` instead of `component`. React requires an upperCase for jsx tag:

```
renderCards(Component){
  let cards =  this.props.list.map(function(cardData){
     return <Component data={cardData}/>
   })
  return cards
}
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks for this! I just wasted two hours trying to figure out why my component did not render. This does the job. Too bad that following recommended JS style has subtle side-effects here...

Comment: Would be cool to see how you call this.  renderCards(<foo/>):?

Comment: `renderCards(foo)`

Comment: shouldn't it be renderCards(Foo)?

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to Damien's answer, here's the same answer using TypeScript with React.

Instead of this, i.e. a simple component without a wrapper ...

```
export const SiteMapContent: FunctionComponent = () => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h1>Site Map</h1>
      <p>This will display the site map.</p>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

... you can pass a component into a wrapper to be rendered there, like this ...

```
const renderContent: FunctionComponent<FunctionComponent> = (Foo: FunctionComponent) => {
  return (
    <div className="foo">
      <Foo />
    </div>
  )
}

export const SiteMap: FunctionComponent = () => {
  return renderContentOne(SiteMapContent);
}

const SiteMapContent: FunctionComponent = () => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h1>Site Map</h1>
      <p>This will display the site map.</p>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Again the name of the parameter must be upper-case e.g. `Foo` not `foo`.

A different way of course, instead of passing a component as asked in the OP is to pass an element instead of a component (in which case the parameter name needn't be upper-case):

```
const renderContent: FunctionComponent<ReactElement> = (foo: ReactElement) => {
  return (
    <div className="foo">
      {foo}
    </div>
  )
}

export const SiteMap: FunctionComponent = () => {
  const foo: ReactElement = <SiteMapContent />;
  return renderContentOne(foo);
}

const SiteMapContent: FunctionComponent = () => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h1>Site Map</h1>
      <p>This will display the site map.</p>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `React.createElment(myLowerCasedComponent)` - I was working through a tutorial in Javascript and porting on the fly to TypeScript.  In TypeScript I got it working like this:

```js
    // PrivateRoute.tsx
    type PropType = {
        component: React.ComponentType
    } & RouteProps
    
    // Component that wraps another component to produce a
    // component which only renders if the user is logged in. If not logged
    // in then the browser is redirected to the signin component.
    const PrivateRoute: React.FC<PropType> = ({ component, ...rest }) => {
        return (
            <Route
                {...rest}
                render={(props) =>
                    isAuth() ? (
                        React.createElement(component)
                    ) : (
                        <Redirect
                            to={{
                                pathname: '/signin',
                                state: { from: props.location }
                            }}
                        />
                    )
                }
            ></Route>
        )
    }
    
    export default PrivateRoute
```

That meant I could call my wrapper like this:

```js
    class Routes extends React.Component {
        render(): React.ReactElement {
            return (
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/signin" exact component={Signin} />
                        <Route path="/auth/activate/:token" exact component={Activate} />
                        <AdminRoute path="/admin" exact component={Admin} />
                        { /* here my param name is 'component' matching than
                             the other routes. Not 'Component=Private' (ugh) */ }
                        <PrivateRoute path="/private" exact component={Private} />
                    </Switch>
                </BrowserRouter>
            )
        }
    }
    
    export default Routes
```

Here my `Private` component is a standard React class based component:

```js
}

type ChangeHandler = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void

class Private extends React.Component<PropType, StateType> {
    render(): JSX.Element {
        return (
            <Layout>
                <div className="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
                { /* stuff here... */ }
                </div>
            </Layout>
        )
    }
}
```