# React Pass Component as props and render it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to render a React Component passed as props.

```
export type SummaryCardProps = {
  site?: string;
  title: string;
  description?: string;
  image?: URL;
  imageAlt?: string;
  ContainerElement: Component;
};

export const SummaryCard: FC<SummaryCardProps> = (props) => {
  return (
    <props.ContainerElement>
      <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
      <meta name="twitter:site" content={new URL('https://' + props.site).toString()} />
      <meta name="twitter:title" content={`${props.title}`} />
      <meta name="twitter:description" content="View the album on Flickr." />
      <meta name="twitter:image" content="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5510/14338202952_93595258ff_z.jpg" />
    </props.ContainerElement>
  );
};
```

The code is for [`@peuconomia/react-meta-tags`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@peuconomia/react-meta-tags). Now, I am trying to make it generic. I want ContainerElelment to be any ReactComponent to keep it plain and simple. I need it to be for any either a `<Head />`(Next.js) or `<Fragment />` for now.

Possible Answer: [Render a react component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38015224/is-it-possible-to-pass-a-react-component-as-argument-in-between-functions-of-a-c). However, when I put Component as type, it gives me error.

`TS2604: JSX element type 'props.ContainerElement' does not have any construct or call signatures`

Comment: Mostly a guess, but other types I'd try would be `JSX.Element` or `React.ReactNode`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved after changing `ContainerType` to be type of `ComponentType<any>`.

```
export type SummaryCardProps = {
      site?: string;
      title: string;
      description?: string;
      imageUrl?: URL;
      imageAlt?: string;
      ContainerElement:  ComponentType;
    };
    
    export const SummaryCard: FC<SummaryCardProps> = (props) => {
      return (
        <props.ContainerElement>
          <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
          {props.site && <meta name="twitter:site" content={props.site} />}
          <meta name="twitter:title" content={props.title} />
          {props.description && <meta name="twitter:description" content={props.description} />}
          {props.imageUrl && <meta name="twitter:image" content={props.imageUrl.toString()} />}
          {props.imageAlt && <meta name="twitter:image:alt" content={props.imageAlt.substring(0, 420)} />}
        </props.ContainerElement>
      );
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

why you need it to be a prop ? there used to be a thing call HOC high order component

a component that returns another component

```js
import React from "react";
export function Wrapper (Component: React.ElementType) {
    return function HOC () {
        return (
            <>
            <Component/>
            </>
        );
    };
}

//---------------------------------------------

export type SummaryCardProps = {
    site?: string;
    title: string;
    description?: string;
    imageUrl?: URL;
    imageAlt?: string;
    ContainerElement:  React.ComponentType;
  };

  const SummaryCard: React.FC<SummaryCardProps> = (props) => {
    return (
      <>
        <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
        {props.site && <meta name="twitter:site" content={props.site} />}
        <meta name="twitter:title" content={props.title} />
        {props.description && <meta name="twitter:description" content={props.description} />}
        {props.imageUrl && <meta name="twitter:image" content={props.imageUrl.toString()} />}
        {props.imageAlt && <meta name="twitter:image:alt" content={props.imageAlt.substring(0, 420)} />}
      </>
    );
  };

  const Wrapped = Wrapper(SummaryCard);

export default Wrapped;
```

Comment: I want the parent to be dynamic. So that the library can be used in any react project.

Comment: I see. In general all you want is to set jsx, per say? You don’t need a parent/wrapper if you wrap your component within <> </> react handles that

Comment: Have you used reactstrap before? You can specify the html tag you want to use for there components. Just look at their code to see how they do it

Comment: I have used react before. But the library is not for next.js alone. So, I need to use a container element. Other wise a Head component would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Change the type of the ContainerElement to `React.ReactNode`

Comment: no, the one you is lookin fow is `React. ElementType`